# Woocommerce - Adding Order ID to Downloadable File Name

Tags: php, python, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a Woocommerce site that creates custom downloadable files. I am looking to add the order ID to the end of the download url before the download ID is created.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I get that. The problem is i don't know which script handles this process. Not looking for free coding, just someone to point me in the right direction.

Comment: The custom downloadable files will be created as a hook to a python script that will be executed after the order payment is confirmed. This function is not currently written. These files will be created in a storage folder and named with the order ID (ex. downloadFolder/downloadFile-334.png).

Comment: So when the order is created I would like to be able to add the order ID (344.png) to the downlod file url (downloadFolder/downloadFile) before the download ID and key are created.

Comment: Not really looking for help with the python. I quess I just need to know where the download url is "attached" to the order.

Comment: There is [`woocommerce_email_attachments` email notifications hook located in `WC_Email` Class](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Email.html#372-379) that you could use.